# Run a system groovy script in jenkins from DSL job plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Getting the **no signature** error for **readFileFromWorkspace()** method in Jenkins seed job (when trying to run a **main.groovy** from dsl job plugin. The **main.groovy** calls a static method from **PrepareBuildPublish.groovy** class to create jobs):

*ERROR: (PrepareBuildPublish.groovy, line 43) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.readFileFromWorkspace() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [WorkspaceLocker.groovy]*

Here is source code for **main.groovy**

```
import models.*
import templates.*

import hudson.FilePath
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

createJobs()

void createJobs() {
    def yaml = new Yaml()

    // Build a list of all config files ending in .yml
    def cwd = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace().absolutize()
    def configFiles = new FilePath(cwd, 'ci-repos').list('*.yml')

    // create jobs for each config file
    configFiles.each { file ->
        def projectConfig = yaml.loadAs(file.readToString(), ProjectConfig.class)
        def project = projectConfig.project.replaceAll(' ', '-')

        PrepareBuildPublish.create(job("${project}-Prepare-Build-Publish"), projectConfig)
    }
}
```

Here is source code for **PrepareBuildPublish.groovy**

```
    package templates

    class PrepareBuildPublish {
        static void create(job, config) {
            job.with {         

                logRotator {
                    daysToKeep(7)
                    numToKeep(15)
                }

                steps {
                    systemGroovyCommand(readFileFromWorkspace('WorkspaceLocker.groovy')){
                        binding('repo','${config.repo}')
                        classpath()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Why the readFileFromWorkspace() method is not found ? If I use the same steps block configuration directly in DSL seed job's *Process Job DSLs* plugin then it works - so it must be something related to groovy and how I invoke this method.

Comment: Think it's delegating to the `steps` object.  Try `systemGroovyCommand(job.readFileFromWorkspace('WorkspaceLocker.groovy'))` (I'll add this as an answer if it works)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion: now I get a different error, but it still doesn't find the method: **No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.readFileFromWorkspace() is applicable for argument types**

Comment: This has been answered on the Job DSL mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/job-dsl-plugin/VoAGdegMpc4/GJ8x5-zhBQAJ